# How does one make a backup of system-connections on to a USB flash/thumb drive?

Tags: permissions, backup

I am using Debian Wheezy.

I would like to back up system-connections (full path is `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections`) on to a USB stick which has been formatted with FAT32.

The folder in question contains the imported profiles of several OpenVPN config files.

I tried to drag the said folder to my USB stick unsuccessfully. The error message is "Permission denied".

---

This post has been edited to include 2 pieces of feedback on slm's answer.

Feedback #1

I didn't know that *rsync* is a package that I had to install. Anyway I installed it using *Synaptic*.

I assumed that *rsync* would work only using *sudo*. Therefore I issued the command *sudo -i* and input my password.

Below are the results:

```
root@hostname:~# rsync -avz /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections /media/USB
sending incremental file list
system-connections/
rsync: chown "/media/USB/system-connections" failed: Operation not permitted (1)
rsync: chown "/media/USB/system-connections/Wired connection 1" failed: Operation not permitted (1)

sent 619 bytes  received 58 bytes  1354.00 bytes/sec
total size is 5482  speedup is 8.10
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1070) [sender=3.0.9]
```

I don't know why I received "Operation not permitted" error.

Strangely when I peered into the contents of my USB flash drive, I saw the contents of system-connections had been copied on to my USB stick.

If the file copy is successful, why the error message?

---

Feedback #2

I was unable to connect to the internet after having done the above file copy using *rsync*.

I rebooted my laptop computer twice and both times after reboot I tried to connect to the internet without success.

What I did next was to uninstall *rsync* using *Synaptic*. Next I rebooted my computer.

Now I'm able to connect to the internet.

What happened?

Comment: You can remove the `a` switch from the rsync command (you can't write UNIX permissions to a FAT drive) and the command will work. Note that this will mean if you try and restore those files *back* to Debian, you will have to manually fix the permissions (you are better off backing up to a UNIX filesystem like ext4). The second part of your question is unrelated and should be removed and asked as its own question.

Comment: @jasonwryan Thanks for the tip. (1) Per manufacturer's instruction, my USB stick has to be formatted with FAT32. It seems that I may not be able to make a backup of `system-connections` on a USB stick after all. (2) Per your advice, I shall be casting my second feedback as a new question.

Comment: Manufacturer's instructions are written for people that only use Windows. Formatting the drive with a real filesystem will not harm it at all...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the USB thumb drive is mounted on the system you can simply use an `rsync` command to back that directory up.

```
$ rsync -vz /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections /path/to/mounted/USB/.
```

If the USB device is reporting that you do not have permission to do so you can use a file browser such as Nautilus to confirm that you have read/write permissions enabled on the device. From within Nautilus with the USB device plugged in you can right click on the device that appears in the left side pane. You'll want to select the "Properties" menu item from there.

[image: ss #1]

From the dialog you can make sure that your username has access to the device.

[image: ss #2]

Comment: Thanks for the tip and the time you took to create those wonderful graphics. I'm unable to say whether your answer works 100%. Please have a look at my original post which has been edited to include my feedback.

Comment: The `a` option (archive) implies `p` (permissions) which will fail on FAT32...

Comment: @jasonwryan - ah good catch, fixed.